# Sending ListView data between forms

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi, I am a newbie to C# and I have no programming background, but I am interested in it.

I want to send data to a ListView, but the data is in the other form. I already saw all the related posts here. I tried copying code from one of the post and changing it according to my needs, but it doesn't work.

Form3:

```
public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public delegate void HandleItemAdded(object sender, ItemAddedEventArgs e);

    public struct ItemAddedEventArgs: EventArgs
    {
        public string PartPrefix;
        public string PartStartNumber;
        public string AssemblyPrefix;
        public string AssemblyStartNumber;
        public string Name;
        public string Profile;
        public string Material;
        public string Finish;
        public string Class;

        public ItemAddedEventArgs(string partprefix, string partstartnumber, string assemblyprefix, string assemblystartnumber, string name, string profile, string material, string finish, string classes)
        {
            PartPrefix = partprefix;
            PartStartNumber = partstartnumber;
            AssemblyPrefix = assemblyprefix;
            AssemblyStartNumber = assemblystartnumber;
            Name = name;
            Profile = profile;
            Material =  material;
            Finish = finish;
            Class = classes;
        }
    }

    public event HandleItemAdded ItemAdded;

    public void RaiseItemAdded(ItemAddedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ItemAdded != null)
            ItemAdded(this, e);
    }

    public void AddToList()
    {  
        RaiseItemAdded (new ItemAddedEventArgs (textBox221.Text, textBox222.Text, textBox223.Text, textBox224.Text, textBox225.Text, textBox226.Text, textBox227.Text, textBox228.Text, textBox229.Text));
    }
}
```

Form1:

```
public void HandleItemAdded(object sender, WindowsFormsApplication1.Form3.ItemAddedEventArgs e)
{
    ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem(textBox221.Text);
    item1.SubItems.Add(textBox222.Text);
    item1.SubItems.Add(textBox223.Text);
    item1.SubItems.Add(textBox224.Text);
    item1.SubItems.Add(textBox225.Text);
    item1.SubItems.Add(textBox226.Text);
    item1.SubItems.Add(textBox227.Text);
    item1.SubItems.Add(textBox228.Text);
    item1.SubItems.Add(textBox229.Text);
    listView1.Add(item1);

    Form3.ItemAdded += Form1.HandleItemAdded; *<-( i dont know if this is the correct place for this.)  
}
```

The error I get is: `type EventArgs in interface list is not an interface`

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do in Form1 is this:

```
public void HandleItemAdded(object sender, WindowsFormsApplication1.Form3.ItemAddedEventArgs e)
        {

            ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem(e.PartPrefix);
            item1.SubItems.Add(e.PartStartNumber);
            item1.SubItems.Add(e.<Member_Name>);
.
.
.

            listView1.Add(item1);

        }
```

And for the error I think following should work for you:

```
public class ItemAddedEventArgs: EventArgs
```

Comment: hi mihirj, thank you for your reply, the error now doesnt appear but the result is the same. it doesnt work. please help.

Comment: did u debug and saw the values of e.PartPrefix and other variables? Also are u sure u need to use Form3.ItemAdded and not ListView.ItemAdded event?